# consecutive punctuation and alpha-numeric characters

Tags: python, regex

Probably a simple question, but I don't have a lot of regex experience. I would like to take a string and select all the consecutive punctuation characters and all the consecutive alpha-numeric characters

This is as close as I could get

```
r="my9zza :)asax"
import re
re.findall(r'(\w+)|([^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)', r)
```

returns

```
[('my9zza', ''), ('', ':)'), ('asax', '')]
```

but I would like

```
['my9zza', ':)', 'asax']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
r = "my9zza :)asax"
import re
print(re.findall(r'\w+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+', r))
```

The problem was having two sets of parentheses in your original code, causing `findall` to return a 2-ple.

If you wanted to keep the original regex, you can also easily transform your result into the desired output with:

```
[x[0] or x[1] for x in result]
```

Comment: but is it possible to do it without that step?

Comment: @mikeL Yes, just use the first bit of code, without the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = [('my9zza', ''), ('', ':)'), ('asax', '')]
final_s = [[b for b in i if b][0] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['my9zza', ':)', 'asax']
```